# Good Source For Mathematics News

Tags: soft-question

Is there a good news source that specifically covers the latest results and findings in pure mathematics which is not an academic journal?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Mathematics is a broad field; a lot of stuff goes on. What sort of things are you interested in seeing? What's your background?

Comment: I don't really have any specific interests, but a website that covers interesting recent developments.

Comment: But I guess if I had to state something, it would be algebraic geometry, algebraic topology, category theory, or any field which currently has a lot of active research.

Comment: glimpse at http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/math